# Specific list of stopwords quanteda

Tags: r, quanteda

I would like to remove a specific list with stopwords using quanteda.

I use this:

```
df <- data.frame(data = c("Here is an example text and why I write it", "I can explain and here you but I can help as I would like to help"))
mystopwords <- c("is","an")
corpus<- dfm(tokens_remove(tokens(df$data, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE), remove = c(stopwords(language = "el", source = "misc"), mystopwords), ngrams = c(4,6)))
```

But I receive this error:

```
> Error in tokens_select(x, ..., selection = "remove") : 
  unused arguments (remove = c(stopwords(language = "en", source = "misc"), stopwords1), ngrams = c(4, 6))
```

How is the right way to use mystopwords list with quanteda?

Answer (score 1):

Building upon the @phiver's answer, this is a standard way of removing specific tokens in **quanteda**. Use of `stopwords()` is not necessary as you are providing a vector of tokens to be removed and `patterns` argument can take a vector, but use `valuetype = 'fixed'` instead.

I used **dplyr** for readabiliity of code but you don't have to.

```
library(quanteda)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(data = c("Here is an example text and why I write it", 
                          "I can explain and here you but I can help as I would like to help"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

mystopwords <- c("is","an")
corpus <- 
  tokens(df$data,
         remove_punct = TRUE, 
         remove_numbers = TRUE, 
         remove_symbols = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_remove(pattern = mystopwords,
                valuetype = 'fixed') %>%
  dfm(ngrams = c(4,6))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work. First, I added `stringAsFactors = FALSE` to the data.frame. The text supplied to `tokens` needs to be a character vector, not a factor. Next, I changed `remove =` from your code, because this needs to be `pattern =`. Last, I the ngram part needs to be in the `dfm` function, not in the `token_remove` function.

When nesting functions, it is better to format the code a bit more. It shows a bit better where potential mistakes can be made.

```
library(quanteda)
df <- data.frame(data = c("Here is an example text and why I write it", 
                          "I can explain and here you but I can help as I would like to help"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

mystopwords <- c("is","an")
corpus <- dfm(tokens_remove(tokens(df$data, 
                                   remove_punct = TRUE, 
                                   remove_numbers = TRUE, 
                                   remove_symbols = TRUE), 
                            pattern = c(stopwords(language = "el", source = "misc"), 
                                       mystopwords) 
                            ), 
              ngrams = c(4,6)
              )
```